# Why does the variable does not store the value in this java program?

Tags: java, string, variable-assignment

I get an error that the variable might not be initialized. Im using a normal String data type and an if..else statement for the decision.This is a program about giving out 5 random cards to the user.The error im getting is on in the first statement of the if else statement, i think the variable assignment method is correct, and even tried it in other programs and it works in those. Can someone find the bug in this?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomCard 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int cardNumber;
    int cardSign;
    String sign;
    Random card = new Random();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
    {

        cardSign = card.nextInt(4);

        if(cardSign == 0)
        {
            sign = "Spades";
        }

        else if(cardSign == 1)
        {
            sign = "Hearts";
        }

        else if(cardSign == 2)
        {
            sign = "Clubs";
        }

        else if(cardSign == 3)
        {
            sign = "Diamond";
        }



        cardNumber = 1 + card.nextInt(13);
        if(cardNumber>1 && cardNumber<11)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println(cardNumber);
        }

        else if(cardNumber == 11)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println("Jack");
        }

        else if(cardNumber == 11)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println("Jack");
        }

        else if(cardNumber == 12)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println("Queen");
        }

        else if(cardNumber == 13)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println("King");
        }

        else if(cardNumber == 1)
        {
            System.out.print(sign + " ");
            System.out.println("ACE");
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend against writing anything this way.  Read about enums and try encapsulating things a bit more.

Comment: Thanks every one the program works but i dont understand why java works this weirdly. I mean int's and double's work perfectly fine without having to initialize them. Any ways  i guess that how they had to make it.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
String sign;
```

to

```
String sign=null;
```

Java compiler always checks if reference is guarantied to have assigned value (even null) before it will let you read/use that reference. Dan Spiteri gave you [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006680/why-does-the-variable-does-not-store-the-value-in-this-java-program/11006738#11006738)  how you can do it without `String sign=null`.

Comment: Not totally correct. Before a local variables is read it must have been guaranteed to be assigned. You are free to set a variable even though it's never been initialized. See Dan Spiteri's answer.

Comment: @SteveKuo Thanks for comment. +1 for Dan Spiteri, and also corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize **String sign=null** or provide a default value at the end of your if statements in an else.

```
if(){
} else if() {
} else {
// default value for sign here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

always try to initilize all your variables.

```
int cardNumber = 0;
int cardSign = 0;
String sign = null;
```

in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables don't have initial values by default. Therefore you need to initialize before you could use them.

Please note that String in java is immutable, so when you assign `sign = "Spades";`, its basically creating a new object. In order to this to happen, it needs to have its initial value which could be either `""` or `null`. This is not the case with `int` variable `cardNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample design that you would be better off stealing, er emulating:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html